# Disable auto-rotate in Jquery Mobile or PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile, cordova, mobile-website

Although cross platform development for mobile devices is so good. There isn't a simple option to disable auto-rotate or lock into one orientation i.e. portrait or landscape.

Is there anyway either in Jquery Mobile, PhoneGap, XUI anywhere ?

If yes then please help. Its driving me nuts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To complete the answer above.

On iPhone add this to -info.plist:

```
<dict>
`.....
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
..........
</dict>
```

on Android to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity   ........      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: is there a way to do this on the fly? For example I have 2 pages which do not need to support orientation changes, but one that does. Any jquery mobile to support this?

Answer (score 5):

For iOS, edit the `PhoneGap.plist` file (e.g. in Xcode). Make sure only portrait is set and uncheck autorotate.

On Android, you need to edit `AndroidManifest.xml`. Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova allows you to set this in config.xml

Just add this line within the `<widget></widget>` tags:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

You can also use `landscape` above for the opposite effect.

[Source: Apache Cordova DOcumentation - The config.xml File](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/config_ref_index.md.html)

Answer (score 0):

On **PhoneGap** you can now specify the **application wide orientation** in the [config.xml](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) file (note that you then won't receive any `orientationchange` event anymore, so this isn't the right solution if you just want to enable/disable the auto rotation on some pages only)

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portait" />
```