# Jquerymobile + Phonegap> how to stop page rotation?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a problem with JqueryMobile and Phonegap app. If I rotate the mobile phone, the app is reloaded from 'index.html'. Is this a bug in Jquerymobile or Phonegap? Is there any way to stop this page reload after a change in rotation or set rotation to a fixed position?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can lock the orientation, by setting this property:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity   ........      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

or IOS in the property list (.plist file)

```
<dict>
`.....
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
..........
</dict>
```

[Disable auto-rotate in Jquery Mobile or PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052400/disable-auto-rotate-in-jquery-mobile-or-phonegap)